# Owl Carousel Progress Bar at bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Hello everybody i got the Owl Carousel Progress Bar [Demo](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/progressBar.html)

but my question is how to show progress bar at the bottom of the slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, please check

```
function buildProgressBar(){
      $progressBar = $("<div>",{
        id:"progressBar"
      });
      $bar = $("<div>",{
        id:"bar"
      });
      $progressBar.append($bar).appendTo($elem);
    }
```

Comment: thanks it's working.